# IIS7 and 32bit Application Pool

Tags: iis-7

Is there a performance compromise if the Application pool in IIS7 is set to 32bit enabled.
Any blog or aritcle on this or any one has experienced this.

Regards

Answer (score 4):

"For optimal performance, use x64 based systems running 32 bit mode applicatoin pools.  You'll get 4 GB per application pool"

http://forums.iis.net/t/1149410.aspx